# face landmark detection with helen database

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, face-detection

I'm going to use CNNs for face landmark detection.(python and tensorflow)

The problem is images in Helen database have different scales.

I think I cannot just resize or crop images because the data is the positions of images.((x,y) coordinates)

however, I found a lot of papers(CNNs) tested their model with Helen dataset.

Does anyone have idea how to deal with helen dataset?

I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest to do:

1. detect faces with open-cv ([here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html))
2. crop bounding box for every face
3. resize the cropped images to the resolution which is needed for the cnn